# Dynamics AX 2012 R2 AIF service not operational for some time after 500 HTTP error with Basic binding

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, aif

We have a non .net client that accesses an AX 2012 R2 AIF service using Basic HTTP binding in a development environment. When the service is invoked with bad XML, understandably, we get a 500 HTTP error code. However, subsequent requests to the service fail for a period of time even after correcting the client. We haven't figured out how long we have to wait.

```
Error details:

HttpStatusCode: 500
Content-Length: 2980
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 26 Jan 2015 21:24:19 GMT
```

```xml
<s:Envelope  xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <s:Fault>
      <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher">a:InternalServiceFault</faultcode>
      <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">
        Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'myOperationName'.
        OperationFormatter encountered an invalid Message body. Expected to find node type 'Element' with name 'MyServiceNameMyOperationNameRequest' and
        namespace 'http://tempuri.org'. Found node type 'Element' with name 'MyServiceNamemyOperationNameRequest' and namespace ''
      </faultstring>
      <detail     xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <ExceptionDetail xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.ServiceModel"      xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
          <HelpLink i:nil="true"></HelpLink>
          <InnerException>
            <HelpLink i:nil="true"></HelpLink>
            <InnerException i:nil="true"></InnerException>
            <Message>
              OperationFormatter encountered an invalid Message body. Expected to find node type 'Element' with name 'MyServiceNameMyOperationNameRequest'
              and namespace 'http://tempuri.org'. Found node type 'Element' with name 'MyServiceNamemyOperationNameRequest' and namespace ''
            </Message>
            <StackTrace>
              at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader reader, MessageVersion version, String action,
              MessageDescription messageDescription, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
              at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeBodyContents(Message message, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
              at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)
            </StackTrace>
            <Type>System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException</Type>
          </InnerException>
          <Message>Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'myOperationName'. OperationFormatter encountered an invalid Message body. Expected to find node type 'Element' with name 'MyServiceNamemyOperationNameRequest' and namespace 'http://tempuri.org'. Found node type 'Element' with name 'MyServiceNamemyOperationNameRequest' and namespace ''</Message>
          <StackTrace>
            at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)
            at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc& rpc)
            at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
            at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
            at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
            at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
          </StackTrace>
          <Type>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException</Type>
        </ExceptionDetail>
      </detail>
    </s:Fault>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Is there a way to recover from this situation without having to wait?

Thank you.

Comment: Please include some error messages. For AX go to System Administration - Periodic - Services and Application Integration Framework - Exceptions. For IIS check Windows Application log or enable error output.

Comment: The good news is I can get back to normal with an IIS reset. Obviously, this is not a good solution in a production environment. I need a solution for the production environment. I'm not able to post the entire error message as it is too long for a comment. Let me see whether I can edit the original post.

Comment: The AIF exceptions doesn't show any error. I suspect the AIF service is not even being invoked because the XML is bad to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Your message format is not valid for this call.

The error clearly says: `Expected to find node type 'Element' with name 'MyServiceNameMyOperationNameRequest' and namespace 'http://tempuri.org'. Found node type 'Element' with name 'MyServiceNamemyOperationNameRequest' and namespace ''`

You have to add *`namespace`* attribute to the request (`'http://tempuri.org`).

Comment: We know what the problem is. The post is about getting back the environment without nay delay after the exception.